Sampling from the multivariate normal in order to generate a BM sample path
Last week, there was a question someone sent about whether one can generate a multivariate normal distribution and use it to sample brownian motion. I tried to explain that this won't work because the properties of independent increments and cov(s,t) = min(s,t) will not hold. I wasn't particularly successful in convincing the person but I was able to find the document below. I can no longer find the original thread but the document below shows that one can generate a sample of BM by
A) generating multivariate normal RV's.
B) multiplying by a time factor ( square root of the time difference between the current $Z_{i+1}$ and $Z_{i}$) and then adding up the $Z_{i}$ up until time ${i+1}$.
So, for the step A), one can generate multivariate normal's but Step B) is crucial for simulating BM. Without the second step, one cannot achieve the other key properties of BM.
I just wanted to add "an ending" to the discussion and hopefully the person who asked
will see this and it will clarify what I was trying to say to him-her. If someone knows where the original posting is and wants to add this link to it, feel free to do that.
https://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4404-Sigman/4404-Notes-sim-BM.pdf
The algorithm might also be in good brownian motion textbooks like Schilling and Wiersema but I've only just started reading them so I don't know that for sure.

Please link to the original question.

Hi Xi'an: It's a good idea but I can't because I can't find it. Usually, I would click on the person who  asked and whose name I thought was rondo, But I could  not find it  this time. I could have the person's name wrong from a memory lapse ? Anyway, I think the question was reasonably clear. Can one generate an MN sample and use these to generate a BM sample. The answer is no unless a crucial second step is added. This step is clearly explained by Sigman in his note that I linked to.

@mlofton While not efficient, why wouldn't simulating from a general MVN work?  At arbitrary time points, $X(t_1),X(t_2),\dots,X(t_n)$ is multivariate normal.

Hi Jarle: You have to do some manipulation afterwards which is the key step that gets you the other two properties. You probably didn't see the original post which is unfortunate but since the BM is an integral process, the $Z_t$ need to be added up in a clever way that gets you the independence of the increments and the cov(s,t) = min(s,t).  It's a pretty straightforward step but it's necessary. Check it out because you'll see what he's doing in that you can't just generate them directly because of the additivity of the integral. Schilling is quite nice as a textbook for BM.

Jarle: I forgot one thing.  Note that, a continuous sample of BM, implies independence of the increments. But independent normals does not imply BM.

I still haven't read far enough to know if Schilling has Sigmn's algorithm in his book. If I find it, I'll let you know. I was having a long discussion with someone and not doing a good job explaining the additivity notion. I looked log and hard after that for something to improve what I was trying to say but only found Sigman's note which surprised me.

Re "since the BM is an integral process, the Zt need to be added up in a clever way that gets you the independence of the increments and the cov(s,t) = min(s,t). It's a pretty straightforward step but it's necessary." That last assertion is not correct.  You refer to one construction or definition of BM but it's not the only one and, as @Jarle points out, there are plenty of other ways to simulate from a BM (many of which are very efficient).  This comes down to the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem.

Hi whuber: I know there are many ways to simulate from a BM. But that was not the question. The original question was: Can one generate from an MVN and construct ( I guess discrete ) brownian motion. The answer is yes if you include a second step which Sigman describes. The normals themselves are not enough. That's all I was saying. I am familar with the Kolmogorov Extension Theorem that says, if you have finite dimensional distributions, then you can generate a BM consistent with those. But that was not the question. Sigman's note answers the question on the first page.

If I answered a different question than was asked, then that's a different issue but, as far as generating MVN's and constructing a sample from a BM, one needs that step. But I agree there are other ways to construct BM ( using say the fact that d(log X) is geometric brownian motion when d(x) is brownian motion ).

whuber: If you looked at the Sigman link, then it's just the "recurisvely define" part that the person who asked the question wasn't getting. I was trying to explain it and I think I pretty much failed which is why the Sigman link was so relevant. That was what I was attempting to originally say in a very garbled way. The whole thing would have made much more sense if I had had the original post. It was from rondo as far as I can remember.

essentially, Sigman's alg is saying that one needs the "Z_t" to be summed ( carefully), in order for the increments to be independent.

I think one of the confusions for statisticians ( not necessarily referring to anyone in particular )  when discussing this topic is that BM is a cumulative ( integral for all you mathematicians ) process whereas statisticians ( myself included ) tend to think of processes as individual observations where $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ have no observations in common. That's ( the no observations in common thing ) is clearly not the case with say "the price of IBM" or the "log price of IBM". Those are BMs because the "return" is the observation.

Hi Jarle and Whuber: I have an email into Sigman asking him if he came up with the algorithm or if it's somewhere else. As whuber said, there are DEFINITELY other ways to construct BM but they all ( atleast the ones that I just quickly glanced at ) are cumulative in one way or the other. So, still the "essence" is connected ( I'm no math guy ) to Sigman's method. I'm not sure why this question got a -1. If either of you thinks something is wrong with Sigman's approach, I'm opened to listening. I just don't see it, yet. In fact, I might be wrong on this and yet never see it.

Jarle: I just read one of your comments again and realize that I never addressed it.  You said "At arbitrary time points, X(t) is multivariate normal" so that;s it.  But that assumes that you already have a BM process to sample from. Yes, you would have an MVN when you sample distinct points from a BM ( because it's a martingale so it works out quite nicely  ) but the question involved generating BM from MVN's. That's not the same thing as sampling MVN's' from an already existing BM. I hope this helps clarify what I was trying to show by providing the link. Your point is well taken.
